# Trouble defining custom route in Rails - all ajax requests are defaulting to the show route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ajax

I'm trying to do an ajax call from the client which aggregates and then returns a single random ad from the server.

**client side ajax call**

`getRandomPerk: function() 
        {
            return $.ajax({url: url + "/advertisements/get_random_ad.json", type: "GET",dataType: "json", error: this.handleAPIError});
        },`

**routes.rb**

`resources :advertisements do
    #collection do
     # get :get_random_ad
    #end

    member do
      get :get_random_ad
    end
  end`

**controller advertisement_controller.rb**

`def get_random_ad
    @advertisement = Advertisement.find_random_advertisement()
end`

**model advertisement.rb**

`def self.find_random_advertisement

    #ids = Advertisement.select("SELECT id FROM advertisements")
    Advertisement.find(1)
  end`

(this is supposed to return a random one but I've got it returning a specific one for debug purposes)

**Server log**

`[time:0.000] Started GET "/advertisements/get_random_ad.json" for 10.240.0.75 at 2016-07-27 18:04:17 +0000
[time:0.200] Processing by AdvertisementsController#show as JSON
[time:0.201]   Parameters: {"id"=>"get_random_ad"}
[time:0.207]   Advertisement Load (0.1ms)  SELECT advertisements.* FROM advertisements WHERE advertisements.id = 0 LIMIT 1
[time:0.208] Completed 404 Not Found in 5.9ms
[time:0.209] 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Advertisement with id=get_random_ad):
  app/controllers/advertisements_controller.rb:16:in show'`

Why is the rails logger saying "processing by AdvertisementsController#show"? Shouldn't it say "processing by AdvertisementsController#get_random_ad"? Maybe this is a fundamental misunderstanding on my part, but I thought that if you defined a new route in the routes.rb file then it would process all requests to that URL.

Comment: What's happening is Rails is seeing `get_random_ad` as a param, and as such it loads up the show action.  Since routes are read from top to bottom, the #show takes precedence.  Are you using the #show action?

Comment: No, I don't have the show action defined anywhere in my routes. I know that's defined by default for my resource, would putting in an `only` keyword override that?

Comment: You bet!  I made a complete answer on the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using the #show action, you can use the `only` or `except` arguments.  something like this should work:

```
   resources :advertisements, except: [:show] do
     member do
       get :get_random_ad
     end
   end
```

However, if you're only using `:get_random_ad`, you can omit the resource and instead use

```
get :random_ad, to: 'advertisements#get_random_ad', as: :random_ad
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped me. The only issue now is the app is trying to direct it to a view, when I only want the JSON. Is there a way I can prevent this? I'm doing all view stuff on the front end. Here's the server log: `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template advertisements/get_random_ad, application/get_random_ad with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :rabl]}. Searched in: app/views`

Comment: You actually want a view.  Even a json response is a 'view'.  Because of Rails convention, it's looking for `advertisements/get_random_ad` with some type of extension or another.  For this, I'd create the file `get_random_ad.json.jbuilder`, and check out the docs for jbuilder.

Comment: You can also override the default view path by using `render`.  Say you have an `Advertisement` object, you can put `render json: <advertisement object>` at the bottom of the action, and you'll achieve a similar result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think there were some basic things I didn't understand about rails until now. Will update my question with the working code!

Comment: No problem!  Feel free to comment here if you have any questions.